# How to convert this nested for loop into a purrr function

Tags: r, for-loop, purrr, nested-for-loop

Alright, I'm trying to replace the use of a nested for loop paired with another for loop with some purrr mapping functions and I'm just not finding it. What I have is a list of dataframes and I know that at least one column in each dataframe contains a match with data in another dataframe not in the list. What I need is to find the columns in the dataframes contained in the list that hold the values that match the values in the external dataframe and rename those columns in the dataframes contained in the list.

To be clear, the dataframes are all of varying numbers of rows, and the data I'm looking for in the list of dfs and the dataframe I'm checking against are hundreds of thousands of random string values - it's not as simple as my example below makes it seem, but the example paints the picture.

Here's a play version of my data.

```
library(dplyr)
x <- data.frame(first = c(1:3, 6:7),
                second = c(1:3, 6:7),
                third = c(1:5))

y <- data.frame(differ = c(10:13),
                other = c(10:13),
                nomatch = rep(5),
                another = c(10:13),
                argh = c(9:12))

z <- data.frame(nothing = c(20:27),
                nope = c(20:27),
                noway = c(16,17, 18, 19, 5, 21, 22, 23),
                still = c(21:28),
                again = c(22:29))

frame_list <- list(first = x, 
                   second = y, 
                   third = z)

check_against <- data.frame(checking = rep(5, times = 5))

col_name_list <- list()

for (i in 1:length(frame_list)) {
  for (j in 1:length(frame_list[[i]])) {
    if (sum(!(is.na(frame_list[[i]][[j]])) 
            & frame_list[[i]][[j]] 
            %in% check_against[[1]]) > 0) {
      col_name_list[[i]] <- names(frame_list[[i]][j])
    }
  }
}

for (i in 1:length(frame_list)) {
  frame_list[[i]] <- rename(frame_list[[i]],
                            I_want_this_one = col_name_list[[i]])
}
```

This gets me what I want, but I would love to replace this with purrr or apply functions.

I've tried a couple of things that don't do anything helpful at all:

```
library(purrr)

map(frame_list, names) %>% 
  imap(., unlist(.), function(x, y) {if (sum(!(is.na(x[[y]])) 
                           & x[[y]] 
                           %in% check_against[[1]]) > 0) {
    col_name_list[[y]] <- names(x[[y]])
    
  }
    x[[y]] <- rename(x[[y]],
                    I_want_this_one = col_name_list[[y]])
    })

# or this
map(frame_list, unlist) %>% 
  imap(., names(.), function(x, y) {if (sum(!(is.na(x[[y]])) 
                                             & x[[y]] 
                                             %in% check_against[[1]]) > 0) {
    col_name_list[[y]] <- names(x[[y]])
    
  }
    x[[y]] <- rename(x[[y]],
                     I_want_this_one = col_name_list[[y]])
  })
```

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around a functional approach to accomplishing this.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first purrr call, give the frame_list, and for the second one, give it the names of the data table. I added a blah column to dataframe y, also changed

```
library(dplyr)
x <- data.frame(first = c(1:3, 6:7),
                second = c(1:3, 6:7),
                third = c(1:5))

y <- data.frame(differ = c(10:13),
                other = c(10:13),
                nomatch = rep(5),
                blah=rep(5),
                another = c(10:13),
                argh = c(9:12))

z <- data.frame(nothing = c(20:27),
                nope = c(20:27),
                noway = c(16,17, 18, 19, 5, 21, 22, 23),
                still = c(21:28),
                again = c(22:29))

frame_list <- list(first = x, 
                   second = y, 
                   third = z)

check_against <- rep(5, 5)

col_name_list=purrr::map(frame_list, function(w) {
  m=purrr::map_lgl(w, function(x) {
    return(any(unlist(x) %in% check_against))
  })
  names(w)[m]
})

col_name_list
```

output

```
$first
[1] "third"

$second
[1] "nomatch" "blah"   

$third
[1] "noway"
```

Comment: This sent in the right direction - got me about 90% of the way there. I was also wanting to get to change the names of the columns in the dataframes. I wound up going with using a variation on what you have here, using `purrr::detect_index` rather than `map_lgl` and after the two functions piping to a `map2` to assign the col names.

This was a MASSIVE help, and it got me in the right mindframe for thinking about how these purrr functions work. THANK YOU!